# Is Google Website Optimizer omitting my query data transfer?

Tags: google-website-optimizer, postdata, ab-testing

**Symptom:** I'm running a Google Website Optimizer A-B test on a web page, which is reached after the user fills out a form.  The form data appears to arrive successfully when GWO does not fire a redirect (when the default page is reached after submitting the web form).  The data does *not* appear to arrive, however, when the alternate page is reached (i.e. when GWO redirects the user).

**Details:** I wouldn't attribute this to GWO, except that in my development environment, where I was obliged to comment out the GWO javascript, everything works as it should do.  (The GWO code had to be omitted, of course, to prevent my browser redirecting me to the production environment, i.e. the live version of my site.)  (Naturally, without the GWO code in place, I had to hard code a change to my form's `action` attribute in order to verify that my query data was handled successfully by the alternate destination page.)

Really, it looks as though GWO is just failing to pass on the requisite query parameters when it performs its redirect, but that seems unlikely.  Can you give me any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed (rather): I changed the form to pass GET (not POST) data, and indeed, GWO was able to collect that query data and pass it on to the new URL.  (I find that surprising, since the url is stipulated, and I should have thought it easier to accept and pass on POST data.)